# init Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Code is below

```
import findspark
findspark.init(r'C:\Users\user\Documents\spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7')
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Basics').getOrCreate()
```

Got error
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number

Disclaimer: Already added `JAVA_HOME` to env variables, I didnt needed to add `spark` as i am calling init

Already went through so many links to check the error could not resolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your Java version? Adding `JAVA_HOME` to your path won't help if you've got a non-compatible version of Java. Java v8 is by far the easiest to get running but [the docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/) say that you should be able to get v11 running.